# find patterns from a list of word

Tags: design-patterns, grep, matching

Is there a way of matching a list of words from a file.
I have two files, A and B. A has a list of words

```
A
abcd
xyzt
```

And file B

```
B
abcdefgh abcd
abcdytqw wert
zswertyu xyzt
```

I want to extract line 1 and 3 from fileB. I want to match A to the second column of B and if it matches print that line of B.

Output will be

```
abcdefgh abcd
zswertyu xyzt
```

I have tried this using grep in perl in a for loop. But it is too slow.
I have more than 100K list.

Comment: Would it be unreasonable to load file A into memory?

Comment: @mr2ert how do you mean?

Comment: I just went ahead and whipped up some code, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This way loads all of A into a set to speed things up. If you don't load A into memory then you will have to compare each line of A against the entirety of file B. By loading A into memory you only have to go through each file once. Also since A is in memory it will be much quicker to check if the second column of B is in A.

Here is an example of this in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def load_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        Aset = set()
        for line in infile:
            word = line.strip()
            if word == '':
                continue
            Aset.add(word)
    return Aset

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Aset = load_data('A')

    with open('B', 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            # Assumes that each line in B will have at least 2 columns.
            # And that the column you are checking against is the last.
            word = line.strip().split()[-1]
            if word in Aset:
                print line.strip()
```

This will not work if the machine does not have enough (free) memory to load all of file A into the set.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have not used python and wouldn't know how to run this. Please advise. Shall I copy this as my script and then how do i run it? Do i just change the 'A' and 'B' with my file names?

Comment: Yeah, and the script will have to be run in the same directory that has the two files. You can either run it by doing: python ./scriptName.py or chmod +x ./scriptName.py ; ./scriptName.py

Comment: I get the following error message File "./extractMAtches.py", line 20
    word = line.strip().split()[-1]
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block. my data is tab delimited can it be because of that?

Comment: No, split() will split on tabs.  IndentationError has to do with how the code if formatted.  If it looks like you have the same indentation as my code, then the issue is probably with mixed tabs.  Make sure to use 4 spaces for all of your indentation levels.